# C# not returning all 'FileInfo' properties in API call

Tags: c#

Given the following API function:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDirFiles(string dir)
{
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

    if (directory.Exists)
    {
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = directory.EnumerateFiles();
        return Ok(files);
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

When I call it with "D:\", I receive the following back

```
[
    {
        "OriginalPath": "DisableReadOnly.bat",
        "FullPath": "D:\\DisableReadOnly.bat"
    },
    {
        "OriginalPath": "KillDotNet.bat",
        "FullPath": "D:\\KillDotNet.bat"
    }
]
```

However while debugging this, when the return is called, the *files* object shows all of the FileInfo properties:

[image]

Why is it that only the OriginalPath & FullPath properties are returned though?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer but if you create an API to be used over HTTP, you should definitely define a return type that will explicitly hold the information you want to return. While unlikely, if `FileInfo` changes, your interface will change, too. And, if you ever want to add extra data to a file, you'll have do an interface-breaking change because you can't change `FileInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the base class of `FileInfo`, `FileSystemInfo`, implements the interface `ISerializable`, which controls how the class is serialized.  Look at the source code for `FileSystemInfo.GetObjectData(...)`:

```
public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, this.FullPath, false, true);
    info.AddValue("OriginalPath", this.OriginalPath, typeof(string));
    info.AddValue("FullPath", this.FullPath, typeof(string));
}
```

Notice that these are the same two properties in your serialization result.  So, if you want extra properties from `FileInfo`, you'll need to create your own class, map properties from `FileInfo` to your class, and serialize *that*.

From [Newtonsoft's documentation on `ISerializable`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable):

> Types that implement ISerializable are serialized as JSON objects. When serializing, only the values returned from ISerializable.GetObjectData are used; members on the type are ignored. When deserializing, the constructor with a SerializationInfo and StreamingContext is called, passing the JSON object's values.
>
> In situations where this behavior is not wanted, the JsonObjectAttribute can be placed on a .NET type that implements ISerializable to force it to be serialized as a normal JSON object.